# how to position the screen and window for winter mode with a double hung window

Tags: windows, exterior

my double hung windows have a half screen and a half window, how should they be positioned for winter mode? Should the window be on the lower half or the upper half?  These are new windows, but so drafty.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean that you have a double hung window (two individual glass sashes, both slide up and down independently), but only have a screen that covers one sash? If so, the problem with drafts has _nothing_ to do with the position of the screen, but with air leaking through the window (unlikely since they're new), or _around_ the window (more likely due to poor installation without spray-foam insulation filling every nook and cranny in the wall cavity).

Comment: Can you perhaps post a photo of your window, with the screen and inner-window parts? Also, if you're getting drafts, that means there may be an insulation issue irrespective of the positioning of the parts.

Comment: If you put the glass half at the bottom, does it's frame make contact with the top window?